# API to like a track in beats

Tags: beatsmusic

Is there any API to "like" a track? Something similar to the native beats application. I would like the same ability. I couldn't find any such API in https://developer.beatsmusic.com/docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can allow users to "like" and "hate" tracks and albums with the API. On the developer portal, you will find this information under docs/read/users/Ratings, Ratings_Lookup, Ratings_Update, Ratings_Delete.

**Links to individual sections:**

[Ratings](https://developer.beatsmusic.com/docs/read/users/Ratings)

[Ratings lookup](https://developer.beatsmusic.com/docs/read/users/Ratings_Lookup)

[Ratings Update](https://developer.beatsmusic.com/docs/read/users/Ratings_Update)

[Ratings Delete](https://developer.beatsmusic.com/docs/read/users/Ratings_Delete)

The parameters under users/Ratings_Update may be the exact parameters you are looking for:

**Name:** rating
**Description:** Rating value. Pass in 1 to indicate a “like”. Pass in 0 to indicate a “hate”.
(Allowed Values: 1, 0)

**Example Request:**

```
curl -X PUT "https://partner.api.beatsmusic.com/v1/api/users/1234567890/ratings/tr99753579" \
    -d "rating=1" \
    -d "access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]"
```